# How to install librsync

Tags: centos, yum, pecl, librsync

Trying to install the php-rsync module using pecl and I'm receiving the following errors:

CentOS 6.3

```
[root@]# pecl install rsync
 Failed to download pecl/rsync within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.1.0, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/rsync-0.1.0" to install
 install failed

[root@]# pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/rsync-0.1.0
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading rsync-0.1.0.tgz ...
Starting to download rsync-0.1.0.tgz (575,174 bytes)
.........done: 575,174 bytes
130 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootYfRWsd/rsync-0.1.0
running: /var/tmp/rsync/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -    I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... invalid
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for rsync support... yes, shared
checking for rsync library to use... bundled
not found
checking for librsync files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please install librsync or put source unter librsync directory here
ERROR: `/var/tmp/rsync/configure' failed

[root@]# yum install librsync
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.plusline.de
 * epel: mirror.kiewel-online.ch
 * extras: ftp.plusline.de
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
Setting up Install Process
Package librsync-0.9.7-13.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So the big thing is `configure: error: Please install librsync or put source unter librsync directory here` yet I have librsync installed.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

```
yum install librsync-devel
```